# Vuejs best practices for defence against interface attacks from editing state variables in browser

Tags: vue.js

Given something simple like this:

```
<Dashboard v-if="$store.getters.ui.user.role == 'staff'/>
<Dashboard v-if="$store.getters.ui.user.role == 'manager'/>
```

... what is the best practice for defending against someone changing user.role from 'staff' to 'manager' in the browser.

(Of course, data is loaded from the server based on role here, so at best the curious user will see an empty and slightly broken interface, but better if they see nothing at all). Other than obfuscation of the rather obv's user.role=='staff', I can't see any way around it.

Comment: How could they change that? Where do you keep that data?

Comment: In the example above it's in a vuex store (obviously there's server side auth going first)

Comment: How can someone manipulate your data in the vuex `state`?

Comment: To be honest - I'm not sure - it's well googled but not well documented. I just assume that anything on client side can be manipulated one way or another given enough google-fu, tenacity and expertise!

Comment: Right, so first of all, don't download data the user should not (don't have permissions to) see . Second, if somebody manipulates the code then he is aware he might crash the application, isn't he? Don't worry about it. The only thing to worry is to NOT download any sensitive data at all from the server.

Comment: @AdamOrlov - I disagree with "don't worry about it". Of course, don't send any sensitive data, that's 101. However if there is a chance that vuex state can be manipulated in the browser, then this brings up considerations for the interface too. For example, elements of your admin interface might give clues to business process that you wouldn't want exposed to client users.

Comment: Can you give an example of such a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to prevent a user from being able to change the client-side code provided to him. The solution you mentioned is the right approach. Never trust the user with any sensitive data unless verified by your server.

This means that while a user with bad intentions might be able to change his role to "manager" and thereby get access to the dashboard (or even remove the if-statement only rendering the Dashboard conditionally - the code is there), the dashboard he sees cannot contain any sensitive data only supposed to be visible to users with a "manager" role.

The key is not providing the user any data he is not supposed to see in the first place, not obfuscate the data passed in hopes the user won't notice. You are not protecting against the average user but rather somebody who knows how to code and has the intention of breaking your application. Obfuscated code is a small hurdle and not sufficient to prevent attackers from seeing and understanding the underlying logic.